# how to use sql server packages in go

Tags: sql, database, go

I use the denisenkom/go-mssqldb package for connecting to SQL server in go but I don't know how to write the connecting code,
what are the arguments of this method : `sql.Open()` for example when we say :
`db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "user:password@/database")`
what do `"mysql"` and `"user:password@/database"` refer to?

and in which part of the program we should tell the name of the database which we want to use in the program? I mean in which part of the code we introduce the name of the database we want to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"mssql" is the protocol/driver/database type you are connecting to. `"user:password@/database"` is the connection string. See [this example](https://github.com/denisenkom/go-mssqldb/blob/master/examples/simple.go) for the components of this String.

Your application typically knows the database it wants to connect. Or at last when the user logs in.

Comment: tnx for your help :) I have another question, should we change this arguments? If we don't change them would something be wrong?

Comment: @rahele, each distinct question should be posted on SO independently from others.  This does not affect your reputation (those points) in any way -- in case you're worried.